# Hadoop + warnings as slow block-receive from data-node machines

Tags: networking, linux-networking, redhat, hadoop, hdfs

We have Hadoop cluster with `487` data-nodes machines ( each data-node machine include also the Service node-manager ) , all machines are physical machines ( DELL ) , and OS is RHEL 7.9 version.

Each data-node machine have 12 disks, each disk is with size of 12T

Hadoop cluster type installed from HDP packages ( previously was under Horton-works and now under Cloudera )

Users are complain about slowness from spark applications that run on data-nodes machines

And after investigation we seen the following warning from data-node logs

```
2024-03-18 17:41:30,230 WARN  datanode.DataNode (BlockReceiver.java:receivePacket(567)) - Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 401ms (threshold=300ms), downstream DNs=[172.87.171.24:50010, 172.87.171.23:50010]
2024-03-18 17:41:49,795 WARN  datanode.DataNode (BlockReceiver.java:receivePacket(567)) - Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 410ms (threshold=300ms), downstream DNs=[172.87.171.26:50010, 172.87.171.31:50010]
2024-03-18 18:06:29,585 WARN  datanode.DataNode (BlockReceiver.java:receivePacket(567)) - Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 303ms (threshold=300ms), downstream DNs=[172.87.171.34:50010, 172.87.171.22:50010]
2024-03-18 18:18:55,931 WARN  datanode.DataNode (BlockReceiver.java:receivePacket(567)) - Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 729ms (threshold=300ms), downstream DNs=[172.87.11.27:50010]
```

from above log we can see the `warning Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took xxms` and also the data-nodes machines as `172.87.171.23,172.87.171.24` etc.

from my understanding the exceptions as Slow `BlockReceiver write packet to mirror` indicate maybe on delay in writing the block to OS cache or disk

So I am trying to collect the reasons for this warning / exceptions , and here there are

1. delay in writing the block to OS cache or disk
2. cluster is as or near its resources limit ( memory , CPU or disk )
3. network issues between machines

From my verification I not see **disk** or **CPU** or **memory** problem , we checked all machines

From network side I not see special issues that relevant to machines itself

And we also used the iperf3 ro check the Bandwidth between one machine to other.

here is example between `data-node01` to `data-node03`  ( from my understanding and please Correct me if I am wrong looks like Bandwidth is ok )

From data-node01

```
iperf3 -i 10 -s

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  7.90 GBytes  6.78 Gbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-20.00  sec  8.21 GBytes  7.05 Gbits/sec
[  5]  20.00-30.00  sec  7.25 GBytes  6.23 Gbits/sec
[  5]  30.00-40.00  sec  7.16 GBytes  6.15 Gbits/sec
[  5]  40.00-50.00  sec  7.08 GBytes  6.08 Gbits/sec
[  5]  50.00-60.00  sec  6.27 GBytes  5.39 Gbits/sec
[  5]  60.00-60.04  sec  35.4 MBytes  7.51 Gbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-60.04  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-60.04  sec  43.9 GBytes  6.28 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

From data-node03

```
iperf3 -i 1 -t 60 -c 172.87.171.84

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   792 MBytes  6.64 Gbits/sec    0   3.02 MBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   834 MBytes  6.99 Gbits/sec   54   2.26 MBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   960 MBytes  8.05 Gbits/sec    0   2.49 MBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   896 MBytes  7.52 Gbits/sec    0   2.62 MBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   790 MBytes  6.63 Gbits/sec    0   2.70 MBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   838 MBytes  7.03 Gbits/sec    4   1.97 MBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   816 MBytes  6.85 Gbits/sec    0   2.17 MBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   728 MBytes  6.10 Gbits/sec    0   2.37 MBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   692 MBytes  5.81 Gbits/sec   47   1.74 MBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   778 MBytes  6.52 Gbits/sec    0   1.91 MBytes
[  4]  10.00-11.00  sec   785 MBytes  6.58 Gbits/sec   48   1.57 MBytes
[  4]  11.00-12.00  sec   861 MBytes  7.23 Gbits/sec    0   1.84 MBytes
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec   844 MBytes  7.08 Gbits/sec    0   1.96 MBytes
```

Note - Nic card/s are with `10G` speed ( we checked this by ethtool )

We also checked the firmware-version of the NIC card

```
ethtool -i p1p1
driver: i40e
version: 2.8.20-k
firmware-version: 8.40 0x8000af82 20.5.13
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:3b:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

We also checked from kernel messages ( `dmesg` ) but no seen something special.

here few other examples from machines that are typical for all machines

**from dmesg**

```
[ 8910.032800] perf: interrupt took too long (3264 > 3131), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 61000
[10472.999301] perf: interrupt took too long (4112 > 4080), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 48000
[13881.302673] perf: interrupt took too long (5231 > 5140), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 38000
[19118.612768] warning: `lshw' uses legacy ethtool link settings API, link modes are only partially reported
[24899.873110] perf: interrupt took too long (6539 > 6538), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 30000
[241682.630383] perf: interrupt took too long (8182 > 8173), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 24000
```

from ethtool

```
Settings for p5p1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseX/Full
                                10000baseSR/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseX/Full
                                10000baseSR/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

**from smartctl**

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST2000NM0155
Revision:             DT31
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Formatted with type 2 protection
8 bytes of protection information per logical block
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c5009484f99f
Serial number:        ZC21D83H
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Tue Mar 19 15:57:43 2024 UTC
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Grown defects during certification <not available>
Total blocks reassigned during format <not available>
Total new blocks reassigned <not available>
Power on minutes since format <not available>
Current Drive Temperature:     29 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        60 C

Manufactured in week 33 of year 2017
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  93
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  1820
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate Cache) information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 186667170
  Blocks received from initiator = 1275068102
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 1770226642
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 2229185660
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 0

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 41721.87
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 53

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:   3668927007        9         0  3668927016          9    1197190.371           0
write:         0        0       386       386        386     849663.857           0
verify:     8968        0         0      8968          0          0.000           0

Non-medium error count:      662

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                  96       3                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self-test duration: 13740 seconds [229.0 minutes]
```

from iostat on one of the data-node

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          45.81    0.00    3.92    4.09    0.00   46.18

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sdh               4.75        26.19       155.21   22283500  132053386
sde             126.62     13137.47      3707.88 11177781537 3154781160
sdf              96.12     12452.01      1084.80 10594563333  922986408
sdg              96.70     13152.62      1084.87 11190668113  923042672
sdb             116.82     13834.69      3637.37 11770994845 3094793700
sda             116.94     13900.15      3659.90 11826688565 3113955968
sdc             120.05     13680.79      4497.98 11640055245 3827023720
sdd              84.66     12973.68      1044.57 11038424341  888755400
```

from free -g

```
free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            314         234           0           2          79          76
Swap:            15           1          14
```

**from dmesg about CPU**

```
dmesg  | grep CPU
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 32 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] smpboot: Ignoring 160 unusable CPUs in ACPI table
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:5120 nr_cpumask_bits:32 nr_cpu_ids:32 nr_node_ids:2
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=32, Nodes=2
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=5120 to nr_cpu_ids=32.
[    0.184771] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
[    0.184943] TAA: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    0.184944] MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    0.324340] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz (fam: 06, model: 4f, stepping: 01)
[    0.327772] smpboot: CPU 1 Converting physical 0 to logical die 1
[    0.408126] NMI watchdog: enabled on all CPUs, permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.436824] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
[    0.436828] TAA CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html for more details.
[    0.464933] Brought up 32 CPUs
[    3.223989] acpi LNXCPU:7e: hash matches
[   49.145592] L1TF CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See CVE-2018-3646 and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/l1tf.html for details.
```